# Replace the values of the second position in a list given two conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, conditional

Suppose I have the following list:

https://pastebin.com/zFin7kkB

and I have a given value of `maxDh` (let's say 0.5) . How can I replace only the values in the second position with a given operation (e.g. `maxDh*5`) only when the values of the first position are greater than `74` and `maxDh` is lower than `1.2` (as in this case)?. For example given that in this example `maxDh=0.5`, then I would get: `{{40,0.0712996},{40.,0.0712996},{40.,0.0712996}......{74.0202,2.5},{74.0404,2.5},{74.2023,2.5}....etc.`

Thank you very much in advanced,

Comment: Perhaps `list /. {a_?(# > 74 &), b_?(# < 1.2 &)} :> {a, 2.5}` ? Can you explain what `dhMax` is here though? Is it the second element of each pair?

Comment: Looks good, comparing `ListPlot[%]` before & after

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you!. In this example `maxDh` (which I corrected in the EDIT) is the number that tells me if the condition should be done or not. Anytime that  `maxDh` is lower than 1.2, then I need to replace all of the values in the second position with the given operation only when the values of the first postion are greater than 74. So, In the case of your code perhaps it would be something like: `list /. {a_?(# > 74 &), b_?(maxDh < 1.2 &)} :> {a, 2.5}`? but it does not seem to work like this

Comment: Also, it is worth mentioning that `maxDh` has nothing to do with the list. It's just a number I use in my code that tells me if I should apply the requested code or not. If it is below 1.2 then I applied the requested code with the condition, if It is greater than 1.2, then simply the list remains the same and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
Clear[list]
list = ToExpression@Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/zFin7kkB"];

ClearAll[conditionalreplace]
conditionalreplace[list_List, maxDh_: 0.5, threshold_: 1.2] := 
 If[
   maxDh < threshold,
   list /. {a_?(# > 74 &), b_} :> {a, 5 maxDh}, 
   list
 ]

ListLinePlot[{list, conditionalreplace[list]}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: yes! Thank you very much !

Comment: MarcoB, I have posted a similar question but with some modification here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/222505/replace-the-values-of-second-position-in-a-list-with-the-values-of-another-list . Perhaps you can help me there too as you are already familiar with the problem. Thanks !