# Replace the values of second position in a list with the values of another list given a condition

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

If I have the following two lists:

list1= https://pastebin.com/zFin7kkB

list2= https://pastebin.com/8ymCin6d

where the first element of both list is the same. How can I replace the values in the second position in `list1` with the values of the sencond position of list2 multiplied by 1.2, only when the values of the first position in `list1` and `list2` are greater than 74?. For example, I would like to obtain a list that would look like: `{{40,0.0712996},{40.,0.0712996},{40.,0.0712996}......{74.0202,0.0594163*1.2},{74.0404,0.059451*1.2},{74.0606,2.5}....etc`. where `0.0594163*1.2`, `0.059451*1.2` and `0.0594857*1.2` are the values of `list2` at the same temperature greater than 74 multiplied by 1.2.

Thank you in advanced,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three of many possible ways:

### 1)

```
Select[list1,#[[1]]<=74&]~Join~(Select[list2,#[[1]]>74&]/.{x_,y_}:>{x,1.2y})
```

### 2)

```
Table[If[list1[[k,1]]<=74,list1[[k]],MapAt[1.2#&,list2[[k]],2]],{k,Length[list1]}]
```

### 3)

```
list3=Transpose[{list1[[All,1]],list1[[All,2]],list2[[All,2]]}];
list3/.{x_,y_,z_}:>{x,If[x<=74,y,1.2 z]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Vitaliy Kaurov!. They both work great !

Comment: @John I added a method and corrected a typo in Method 2) above.

Answer (score 0):

Get the position of elements in `list` that are greater than or equal to 74:

```
positions=PositionIndex[UnitStep[dlist[[All,1]] - 74]][1];
```

Extract these positions from `list2` and make the desired modification:

```
modified=Extract[dlist2,List/@positions].{{1,0},{0,1.2}};
```

Use `ReplacePart` to generate the desired output from `list`:

```
ReplacePart[dlist, Thread[positions-> modified]]
```

> {{40, 0.0712996}, {40.0303, 0.0712996}, {40.1206, 0.0712996}, {40.2709, 0.0712996}, {40.4812, 0.0712996}, {40.7515, 0.0712996}, {41.0818, 0.0712996}, {41.4721, 0.0712996}, {41.9224, 0.0712996}, {42.4327, 0.0712996}, {43.003, 0.0712996}, {43.6333, 0.0712996}, {44.3236, 0.0712996}, {45.0739, 0.0712996}, {45.8842, 0.0712996}, {46.7545, 0.0712996}, {47.6848, 0.0712997}, {48.6751, 0.0712998}, {49.7254, 0.0712999}, {50.8357, 0.0713001}, {52.006, 0.0713005}, {53.2363, 0.0713013}, {54.5266, 0.0713027}, {55.8769, 0.0713055}, {57.2872, 0.0713108}, {58.7575, 0.0713215}, {60.2878, 0.0713431}, {61.8781, 0.0713877}, {63.5284, 0.0714818}, {65.2387, 0.0716832}, {67.009, 0.0721217}, {68.8393, 0.0730904}, {70.7296, 0.0752558}, {72.6799, 0.0801279}, {74.6902, 0.0727345}, {76.7605, 0.0779653}, {78.8908, 0.084852}, {81.0811, 0.0939294}, {83.3314, 0.105899}, {85.6417, 0.121673}, {88.012, 0.14242}, {90.4423, 0.169613}, {92.9326, 0.20505}, {95.4829, 0.250837}, {98.0932, 0.309269}, {100.764, 0.382531}, {103.494, 0.472162}, {106.284, 0.578142}, {109.134, 0.697711}, {112.045, 0.8242}, {115.015, 0.94674}, {118.045, 1.05203}, {121.136, 1.12888}, {124.286, 1.17383}, {127.496, 1.19332}, {130.767, 1.19897}, {134.097, 1.19992}, {137.487, 1.2}, {140.937, 1.2}, {144.448, 1.2}, {148.018, 1.2}, {151.648, 1.2}, {155.339, 1.2}, {159.089, 1.2}, {162.899, 1.2}, {166.77, 1.2}}

In the above, `dlist` and `dlist1` are *down*-sampled versions of `list` and `list1`, respectively (sampled every 100th element)